# Why doesn't the voltage divider rule work with a TMP36 temperature sensor but does work with a thermistor

Tags: voltage, temperature

[image: Circuit design for temperature sensorstrong text]

I recently got an assignment to investigate the relationship between a temperature sensor and its resistance.

Because of the lockdown I was required to use simulation.  The simulator only has a temperature sensor. We have to design this circuit with the voltage divider rule but adding the resistor along side with the temperature sensor doesn't work.  Does anyone know why?

Comment: The two fundamental ideas behind the voltage divider are 1) you have two resistors in series and 2) the current flowing through them is identical. The thermistor is a resistor and the TMP36 is not. The second place most people go wrong with the resistor divider is that they try to add something else at the node where the resistors come together and create an alternate current path. This violates 2) because once current can take an alternate path, the current in the two resistors is no longer identical.

Answer (score 1):

According to the datasheet of the TMP36, it outputs a voltage whereas the thermistor changes resistance and needs another resistor in order to create a variable voltage.

Answer (score 1):

A resistor divider consists of two resistances in series, the pair being connected across some voltage source. If one of those resistances is temperature dependent, then by the resistor divider rule, you have a voltage that varies with temperature. The important thing to realise is that you need *two resistors* for that to work.

The TMP36 is not a resistor, the biggest clue being the fact that it has three terminals, not two.

Internally, the TMP36 is a complete system containing something akin to that afore-mentioned resistor divider *plus all the amplifier circuitry* needed to sense and scale its temperature-dependent voltage. The output voltage from the TMP36 can in no way be likened to a resistance.

Its output is actually more like the output of an opamp, deliberately designed to have as little resistance as impossible. You may consider this output to be equivalent to a voltage source, like a battery or photovoltaic cell, but whose EMF is related to temperature rather than being fixed or light-dependent.

You cannot consider the output of the TMP36 to be some resistance whose value is related to temperature. Nor can you consider the TMP36 power supply pins to possess any properties that you may interpret in such a way.

In fact, its very purpose is to solve all the problems associated with a simple resistive temperature sensor, a thermistor. It's trying to be as far removed from "I'm a resistor" as it's possible to be.

Answer (score 0):

A thermistor is a temperature sensitive resistor (or more accurately a HIGHLY sensitive to temperature resistor, more so than normal resistors) made of metal powders into a very basic semiconductor.

[image]
https://www.eeeguide.com/thermistor-operation/

A TMP36 is an basic semiconductor integrated circuit made primarily of transistors and resistors. It's not quite an advanced logic circuit like digital tenperature sensors but it's chocked full of active components.

From its datasheet:
[image]

As such, a thermistor works in a resistor voltage divider because it works on the same resistor theory of operation, while a TMP36 cannot. Putting the TMP36 in a voltage divider will greatly affect the voltage depending on how much "work" it does and thus give you inaccurate or hard to scale output.